# Default template parameter in Visual Studios 2012

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, function-templates

This question is a followup after [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692406/partial-template-specialization-by-overloading). The actual problem is that default template parameters *for function templates* are not supported by Visual Studios 2012 as indicated by [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.120).aspx).

---

Since default template parameters are not supported by Visual Studios 2012, is there any workaround to have the same result without it? So is it possible to define a template function such as

```
template <typename T, typename Ret = T>
Ret round(T val, Ret ret = Ret()) {
    return static_cast<Ret>(
        (val >= 0) ?
        floor(val + (T)(.5)) :
        ceil( val - (T)(.5))
    );
}
```

without the use of default template arguments? The function works as

```
auto a = round(5.5, int()); // int a = 6
auto b = round(5.5); // double b = 6.0
```

Comment: You can always add an overload, such as `template<typename T> T round(T val);`

Comment: @dyp: Corrected. Thanks. Overload does indeed work. I was confused by my previous example from the linked question. That wasn't a smart question...

Comment: Wouldn't you want the rounding to default to whatever type you assign to rather than the input type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, also, passing a value to force a return type is not really a nice way to do it, use the template argument instead :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <typename Ret, typename T>
Ret round( T val ) {
    return static_cast<Ret>(
        ( val >= 0 ) ?
        std::floor( val + (T) ( .5 ) ) :
        std::ceil( val - (T) ( .5 ) )
        );
}

template <typename T>
T round( T val ) {
    return round<T,T>( val );
}

auto a = round<int>( 5.5 ); // int a = 6
auto b = round( 5.5 ); // double b = 6.0

static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(a), int>::value, "a must be int" );
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(b), double>::value, "b must be double" );

int main() {
    std::cout << a << " " << b; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is an answer to both of my questions. I inserted `round<T>(val)` as return value for the overloaded function which resulted in a compiler error. I linked this answer to the previous question.

Comment: Curious, `round<int>(5)` calls which?

Comment: An ambiguous call… As this is a workaround to a missing feature and calling round with an integer input would probably be an error, i would use `template <typename T> auto round( T val ) -> typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type;` instead, and a static_assert in the 2 arguments version to enforce T to be a floating point value.